# Ошибка синтаксиса PHP

Tags: php

Вот код:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'), name="Vasya" {
    echo "<h1>Привет, хозяин!</h1>";
    }
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo "<h1>Привет, <b>" . $_POST['name'] . "</b>!</h1>";
    }
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
    Введите Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="okbutton" value="OK">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Как многие уже поняли, задача кода - вывести сообщение "Привет, хозяин!", если человек ввел Vaysa, если же что-то другое, то просто "Привет, имя человека!". Но возникает ошибка синтаксиса:

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/tester/public_html/test.ru/test.php on line 7`

Как исправить ошибку и в чем она?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в 7-й строчке. Запятая там совершенно не в тему.

Нада так:

```
if( $_POST['name'] == 'Vasya' ){
    echo '<h1>Привет, хозяин!</h1>';
}else{
    echo '<h1>Привет, <b>' . $_POST['name'] . '</b>!</h1>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да ужжжж... Наверное, всё-таки должно быть так (про запятую верно сказал комментатор):

```
<? if( isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] == 'Vasya' ): ?>
<h1>Привет, хозяин!</h1>
<? else: ?>
<h1>Привет, <b><?= $_POST['name'] ?></b>!</h1>
<? endif; ?>`
```

Но я бы создал новую переменную, присвоил бы ей значение тренарным оператором и вывел бы в одном месте, чтобы не путаться.